# Does a subgroup of a group having a composition series have a composition series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $G$ is a group having a composition series and $H\leq G$. Does $H$ necessarily have a composition series?

If $H\lhd G$, then $G$ has a composition series one of whose terms is $H$, and so $H$ has a composition series. But I'm unsure whether this is true for arbitrary subgroups. Since all finite groups have a composition series, I don't know how I can find a counterexample. Or maybe this is true? Any hints will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't have a composition series, but it's a subgroup of any group which has an element of infinite order. So we can take $H = \mathbb{Z}$ and $G$ any infinite simple group with elements of infinite order, for example $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$.